# How to convert a sequence of uint16 to float32?

Tags: go, casting, modbus

I've a sequence `[66 106 179 86]`(those numbers are two 16bit register in modbus) generated by modbus library([conversion code](https://github.com/goburrow/modbus/blob/master/client.go#L468)), now how can I convert this sequence in a 32 float number?

I've tried `[]uint32{66,106, 179, 86}` as argument for `Float32frombits` but doesn't accept uint32 lists.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Using `math.Float32fromBits()`

We may use [`math.Float32fromBits()`](https://golang.org/pkg/math/#Float32frombits) to obtain a `float32` value from its "binary" representation. But in order to use it, we need the 4 bytes data packed into a `uint32` value. For that, we may use [`binary.ByteOrder.Uint32()`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/binary/#ByteOrder):

```
data := []byte{66, 106, 179, 86}

bits := binary.BigEndian.Uint32(data)
f := math.Float32frombits(bits)
fmt.Println(f)
```

Output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/BIH41d8EAc-)):

```
58.675133
```

This solution is faster if we just want to read a single `float32` value.

### Using `binary.Read()`

Another option would be to use [`binary.Read()`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/binary/#Read) to fill fixed-size values from an [`io.Reader`](https://golang.org/pkg/io/#Reader). If we have our data as a byte slice, we can use [`bytes.NewBuffer()`](https://golang.org/pkg/bytes/#NewBuffer) to obtain an `io.Reader` from it:

```
data := []byte{66, 106, 179, 86}
var f float32
err := binary.Read(bytes.NewBuffer(data), binary.BigEndian, &f)
fmt.Println(f, err)
```

Output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/riBObEhdWaN)):

```
58.675133 <nil>
```

This solution is preferred if we have to read a series of `float32` values from the input.